# Who do I work with next.js for client side and express in node.js for server side

Tags: node.js, next.js

I have now learned to work with nodejs. but now I wanted to learn more about making better websites. So I found next.js, That I have learned the basic of. But I don't understand how I work with them to together.

So my question is, **How to I have a node.js server-side and next.js on the client-side?**

If you have any other thing to learn or tell me, please tell me all I need to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

probably you misunderstood what next.js is.

NodeJS is used to create backend apps that handled HTTP request, [more information about backend](https://www.codecademy.com/articles/back-end-architecture)

[React](https://reactjs.org/) is a JS library to create [Frontend Application](https://www.upwork.com/hiring/development/beginners-guide-to-front-end-development/) which is served by a server. But a React App is a really heavy js file and is really slow to be served, then in order to improve the performances you have to pre-render the html in the server and then send the pre-rendered web page to the client. More about [SSR vs CSR](https://medium.com/walmartlabs/the-benefits-of-server-side-rendering-over-client-side-rendering-5d07ff2cefe8)

Next.JS is a framework to develop SSR React App.

Comment: Okay, make sense. Do you have any suggestions for any type of framework or something like that, which is good for making good node apps? By that I mean, I  have worked with EJS with MongoDB, but I didn't really like the may the two worked together. Maybe I just did I wrong. I have the server side down but is now more about how to make a better connection with the font end. 

Thanks.